# How to handle exceptions when reading settings file?

Tags: python

In reading settings from a JSON file I need to ensure that defaults are loaded if there are any issues.  The current version of the code looks something like this.  It works fine, but I suspect this isn't really a good way to do the job:

```
def _recall_settings_v1(self):
    settings = {}
    try:
        with open(_APP_SETTINGS_FILE, "r") as fp:
            try:
                settings = json.load(fp)
            except ValueError:
                # The file does not have valid syntax or is corrupt
                pass
    except OSError:
        # Trouble reading the file
        pass
    # Load settings if we can read them
    # Otherwise, load defaults and create a new settings file
    if settings:
        self.a = settings["a"]
        self.b = settings["b"]
    else:
        self.a = _DEFAULT_FOR_A
        self.b = _DEFAULT_FOR_B
        # Create a new settings file
        self._store_settings()
```

My next attempt looks much cleaner.  It also works fine.  I guess my questions would be:

Are there any side effects from combining exceptions this way?

Is there a canonical way to reliably save and restore settings to/from files?

I could use some pre-filtering by using the `os` module to determine if the file exists.  While that could remove one exception layer, the reality is that there is no guarantee that the file could be opened or parsed, even if it exists.

```
def _recall_settings_v2(self):
    try:
        with open(_APP_SETTINGS_FILE, "r") as fp:
            settings = json.load(fp)
    except (OSError, ValueError):
        # Trouble reading the file, it is corrupt or has invalid syntax
        # Set to defaults and create new settings file
        self.a = _DEFAULT_FOR_A
        self.b = _DEFAULT_FOR_B
        self._store_settings()
    else:  # Got the data
        self.a = settings["a"]
        self.b = settings["b"]
```

I should add that this is going on an embedded system running MicroPython, which imposes restrictions on modules that can be imported.

In addition to this, the system has to have some failure tolerance.  I am accomplishing this by actually having three copies of the settings files rather than one.  The code tries to read and write from all three and then runs through a majority voting function to decide which settings to load.  I simplified the code examples above to only show handling of a single.

Comment: Consider loading the defaults into a dictionary at the start, perhaps via a `defaults = get_default_settings()` function call.  Then, after you determine the majority settings from your files, you can merge the overridden settings on top of the defaults with. `combined_settings = default | overrides` in Python 3.9+, which will combine the dictionaries.  In earlier versions would need to loop over keys in overrides and merge them into default.
Then, `for key in combined_settings,:` `setattr(self, key, combined_settings[key])`

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll give that a try and see what I might learn.  Thanks.